# someone who willingly "mishears" stuff to support their view?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

Not the best example, but this should hopefully get the point across:

Lets say you have this one friend, who really hates some journalist, maybe a movie or game critic or something. He says something like:

"This guy has no idea what he's talking about! He thinks a game/movie deserves only a 5/10 because of this one thing!"

Even though the journalist gave a very reasonable list of complaints he had with a game/movie and it was not *just* because of "this one thing!".

What do you call such people?

Comment: He didn't *mishear*, he *misinterpreted*. He deliberately misinterpreted.

Comment: @vickyace He didn't write _mishear_, he wrote _'mishear'_.

Comment: The quote marks are significant, as Edwin Ashworth points out. In context, they imply some kind of dishonesty whereas the bare term *mishears* might not.

Comment: @Lawrence What I'm saying is *mishear* means a mistake, which is mostly honest. How can one willingly make an honest mistake, as mentioned by the OP. Although the meaning is obvious because of common use, words should be used for what they are meant. *Misinterpret* is better because "interpret" accounts for things such as mistakes, dishonesty, etc.

Comment: @vickyace Highlighting the dishonesty is exactly what the quotes do, especially coupled with the word *willingly*. Misinterpretations are no more dishonest than mistakes, particularly willing mistakes, and especially willing 'mistakes'.

Comment: The phenomenon OP describes sounds like a [confirmation bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias): "Confirmation bias...is the tendency to search for, interpret, favor, and recall information in a way that confirms one's preexisting beliefs or hypotheses, while giving disproportionately less consideration to alternative possibilities." I would've submitted this as an official answer, except the question is currently on hold. I do agree it would be helpful if we knew how you'd like the term to be used.

Comment: So...do I just need to add if it should be used in a negative or positive context? Cause based on the nature of the word, I thought it was obvious that it would be used in a negative light.

Comment: Closely related, at least: [Words to mean one taking only part of the other's words](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34498/words-to-mean-one-taking-only-part-of-the-others-words/34507#34507)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are **disingenuous**.

> *disingenuous* adjective
>
> not candid or sincere, typically by pretending that one knows less
>   about something than one really does.
>
> "this journalist was being somewhat disingenuous as well as cynical"
>
> *synonyms*:   dishonest, deceitful, underhand, underhanded, duplicitous, double-dealing, two-faced, dissembling, insincere, false, lying,
>   untruthful, mendacious...

[[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/disingenuous)]

Answer (score 2):

I found several:

**Biased**

According to the Cambridge Dictionary:

> showing an unreasonable preference or dislike based on personal opinion

**Partisan**

According to Merriam-Webster:

> a firm adherent to a party, faction, cause, or person; especially :  one exhibiting blind, prejudiced, and unreasoning allegiance

**Tendentious**

Also according to Merriam-Webster:

> marked by a tendency in favor of a particular point of view

Answer (score 2):

A phrase sometimes used to describe this phenomenon is selective listening or selective hearing.

Simon and Garfunkel sang, in The Boxer that "a man hears what he wants to hear and disregards the rest."

The Urban dictionary gives an example of [selective hearing](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=selective%20hearing) in the following dialogue

> "Jimmy, do the laundry and then you can go to the movies."
>
> "Sweet! I can go to the movies!"
>
> "AFTER YOU DO THE LAUNDRY!"
>
> "What? You never said i had to do the laundry."
>
> "I swear, you have selective hearing"

One hears what he wants to hear and disregards the rest.

Another example would be:

> Teacher: Everything you have written is very clearly the most utter drivel.
>
> Pupil: Why,  thank you,  do you really think so, Sir?  My last teacher said nothing I wrote was clear.

Answer (score 1):

Outside the issue of whether or not the journalist (or other exemplar) was being even-handed in the review I'd say that your friend was simply **biased** (*alt. biassed*). Your friend already "hates some journalist" and, it's suggested, disagrees with that journalist's review of Game/Film XYZ on the basis of that **bias**. Your friend is pre-disposed to disagree with (***biased*** against) negative comments from that journalist and possibly also ***biased*** against *any* negative comments about Game/Film XYZ.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/biassed